# Auto-response on a mail non universal group

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Four domain users are part of global security group `HR@companyname.com` running on Windows Server 2008 Standard and Exchange 2007 as a mail non universal group.

Our goal is to create an auto-responder rule, or template that fires at sender. I have created a mail-enabled public folder, with owner permissions for each group member. I have also set up a rule template (response) and I am a little unclear as to the send as permission set, or where to set that up.

Can someone please tell me if I am on the right track? Will I have to do each Outlook client machine (whole group!) the same?

Comment: are public folders a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not have to do any thing for each client. It sounds like you are most of the way there. If you have created the rule on the mail enabled public folder and created a template email then all you should need to do is grant Send As permissions on the public folder mailbox to the user account you used to create the rule (I'm guessing your account), that should be it.